# Which are the "several forms of animation" used by Wes Anderson in Fantastic Mr. Fox?

Tags: film-techniques, animation, fantastic-mr-fox

From the [Wikipedia article for Fantastic Mr. Fox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fantastic_Mr._Fox_%28film%29),

> The film mixes several forms of animation but consists primarily of stop motion.

Besides stop motion, Which other forms of animation did the film use?

Comment: Ok, now it gets really disappointing. :-(

Answer (score 1):

According to IMDB, the film's full cast and crew included several digital compositors. From the descriptions, most of the CGI was used for Lip Syncing the dialogue with the stop motion.